# NetShareEnum access denied

Tags: asp.net

I have asp.net application hosted by IIS 7.5. I use NetShareEnum function to get shared folders from the network computers. The web app runs from LocalSystem so function always return Access Denied error because  LocalSystem don't have share permissions. How I can resolve this? any idea?